# How to find a label in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, label, flowlayoutpanel

I have a c# `FlowLayoutPanel` container to which I am adding a number of labels with `Label.Text` set to different values ie `Label.Text = "ABCDEF"`.

What is the best way to search all the labels in the container to find the 
a particular label with the `Text = "ABCDEF"`?

Thank You

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Could you please share your code to show what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the label with text as follow:

```
foreach (var item in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if (item is Label)
    {
        if ("ASDF" == ((Label)item).Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("found it");
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you know your component's name, you can search it as below:

```
foreach (var item in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("label1", true))
{
    if ("ASDF" == ((Label) item).Text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("found it");
    }
}
```